# Chrome Extension: Schedule notification not resetting data on chrome storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I've developed an app that should trigger an alarm at a specific hour everyday. This alarm will trigger a rich notification, which has a callback function that sets data in the chrome storage.

The issue is:

- If chrome is running the scheduled notification triggers correctly and resets the data in the chrome storage.
- If chrome is not running (e.g.: PC turned off) and I start chrome 1 or 2 hours after the scheduled notification, the data will reset.
- If chrome is not running and I start chrome 6 or 7 hours after (let's say I turn on the PC after my sleep) the data will not reset, even though the scheduled notification triggers.

Creating alarm:

```
chrome.alarms.create("resetDailyValue", {
        when: new Date().setUTCHours(resetTime, 0, 0, 0),
        periodInMinutes: resetTime * 60
    });
```

Schedule notification:

```
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function (alarm) {      
    chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function (keys) {
        dailyValue = keys["dailyValue"];
    });

    if (alarm.name === "resetDailyValue") {
        chrome.notifications.create(resetNotificationOptions,
            function () {
                chrome.storage.sync.set({
                    "dailyValue": dailyDefaultValue
                }, function () {
                    console.log("Daily value reset!");
                });
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the point of setting `dailyValue` in this code? Where does `dailyDefaultValue` come from? Is your background page persistent? The fact that the notification does trigger means `chrome.alarms` works fine, something else is at fault.

Comment: dailyDefaultValue is a const equal to 0. The reason to set dailyValue to 0, is to reset a progress bar in the popup.html file. And as you can see in my bullet times, the setting of the value doesn't work when the extension is offline for a long time.